# Liferay - is user Site Owner?

Tags: liferay, role, owner

I am working on one feature in Liferay 6 and I want it, to be accessible only for Site Owner. I have big problem how to get if user is Site Owner. I can get if user is Administrator using this

```java
if (RoleServiceUtil.hasUserRole(user.getUserId(), companyId,
                "Administrator", true)) {
   //do something
}
```

When I use Site Owner instead of Administrator, then I get this message `Site Owner is not a regular role`

Thanks for help

-Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `permissionChecker`.

First you'll need to include the a TagLib like so:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
```

Then you can place some basic variables on the page (one of which is `permissionChecker`) like so:

```xml
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
```

Then you can simply call,

`permissionChecker.isGroupOwner()` or `permissionChecker.isGroupAdmin()`